# Google App Engine-Cannot Bind to Local Host

Tags: google-app-engine, localhost

I'm currently using GAE and am trying to run my application and am receiving the following error in the logs along with a yellow hazard symbol within the app engine launcher:

```
raise BindError('Unable to bind %s:%s' % self.bind_addr)
google.appengine.tools.devappserver2.wsgi_server.BindError: Unable to bind localhost:9080
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thank you!

Comment: This typically means that some other service already has port 9080 open.  Check the command line options for the dev server and change the ports.

Comment: Hi @TimHoffman, thank you for taking time to help. I had tried to change both of my server ports, and I did eventually get my application to "Run", however, when I try to access the program locally, an error appears in the logs saying "Database is blocked". I'm not entirely sure where to go from here

Comment: What operating system are you running on?  Does your app use Datastore or local MySQL db?

Comment: This sounds very much like you're trying to start the dev_appserver when another dev_appserver is still running.

Comment: Thank you @DaveW.Smith , this was indeed the problem! I was able to isolate my application and have it now run locally! Much appreciated!